# C Programming - Repeat scanf unless user enters "0"

Tags: c, loops, conditional-statements, scanf, exit

Hello I am new to C and trying to make a program that asks for the user to input a whole bunch of numbers. I want to loop `scanf` so that it keeps asking and when the user inputs "0", it stops, reads off the even and odd numbers inputted, and counts them seperatly. Right now I have it to keep asking for new numbers after user presses "Enter" but when i type "0" is just keeps asking for more numbers and doesn't stop. What am I doing wrong? Like I said before, I am very new so baby words are best.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {

    int number_of_integers, sum = 0, i, integer;
    char user_name[128];

    printf("What is your name?\n");
    scanf("%s", user_name);

    printf("\nEnter any real numbers followed by ENTER.\n");
    while (integer != 0) {
        scanf("%s", &integer);
        if (integer == 0)
            break;
    }

    printf("%s, the numbers you entered are broken down as follows:\n", user_name);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: scanf("%s", &integer); ??? Storing string in integer ?

Comment: Yes that was a mistake and now it works when i press 0. Thank you!

Comment: If you have any idea how to record the even/odd numbers inputted and count them, that would be great!

Comment: You can search the internet for that.you can easily find an answer.

Comment: SO is not a tutorial site. You are expected to do research on your own first.

Comment: Understood, thanks for the help

Comment: `integer` need initialize to not zero.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &integer);` --> `scanf("%d", &integer);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a commenter indicated, we aren't a homework or tutoring service, but I'm doing you a favor by producing an actual working example that I just made up. It's up to you now to tailor it exactly to your needs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
    int max=100;
    int integer;
    int even[max];
    int odd[max];
    int index=0;
    int evencount=0;
    int oddcount=0;
    char user_name[128];

    printf("What is your name?\n");
    scanf("%s", user_name);

    printf("\nEnter any real numbers followed by ENTER.\n");
    while (index < max){
        scanf("%d", &integer);
        if (integer == 0)
        break;
        if ((integer % 2) == 0){
            evencount++;
            even[evencount]=integer;
        }else{
            oddcount++;
            odd[oddcount]=integer;
        }
        index++;
    }

    printf("%s, the %d numbers you entered are broken down as follows:\n", user_name,index);
    printf("%d odd integer(s):\n",oddcount);
    while (oddcount > 0){
    printf("%d\n",odd[oddcount]);
    oddcount--;
    }
    printf("%d even integer(s):\n",evencount);
    while (evencount > 0){
    printf("%d\n",even[evencount]);
    evencount--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! What does "[]" mean? For example in odd[oddcount]=integer;

Comment: @BaileyW `odd[]` is any array and when we say `odd[oddcount] = integer` we are storing `integer` into array `odd` at the index `oddcount`. Please read a descent C book to learn the basic stuff in C.

Comment: Thank you, I havent gotten to arrays yet in my class but you explained it very well. I appreciate it